# jQuery - having icons at the end of drop down list items with independant actions

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ive looked around a bit and not found anything so im not even sure if this is possible.

What I want to do is have a drop down list. Each list item is a specific type of a view for a list. Is it possible to add an icon at the end that when clicked will fire off a different action to just selecting the item?

So the user opens the drop down. They see View 1. At the end there is a pencil button image. If they select View 1 the list view changes. If they select the pencil it opens up the edit View dialog for that view.

Is this even possible using javascript/jQuery?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible to assign an action to a text, and a different action to an icon. Did you try anything?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

It won't be do-able with the standard `select` element, however it's definitely possible using `divs` and heavy Javascript/jQuery.

Something similar to how the jQuery plugin [Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/) works - it hides the original `select` element and rebuilds it with `divs`, adding interaction with jQuery (obviously).